# The page you requested is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience, please check back in a few minutes

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api, resource-throttling

I am adding and updating 56 columns(include people picker column) and 4999 rows in sharepoint list through excel using rest api but after some time i get throttle temporary issue and it does not update or add all data.
"The page you requested is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience, please check back in a few minutes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online uses throttling to maintain optimal performance and reliability of the SharePoint Online service.

Throttling limits the number of user actions or concurrent calls (by script or code) to prevent overuse of resources.

Best practices to handle throttling:

1.Reduce the number of operations per request

2.Reduce the frequency of calls

3.Decorate your traffic so we know who you are (see section on traffic decoration best practice more on that below)

4.Leverage the retry-after header

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online